# SQL Query When not Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report I am working on and would like to incorporate a record that I am thinking I cant have exist but hopefully someone can prove me wrong. I was trying to find ways to get around it but honestly am not that savvy in SQL. Query is specifically around getting Data from SCCM 2012 DB for machine records that are not win7 enterprise and do not have office 2013. Problem point I am having is the 2013 factor when the SoftwareFile table does not have a record of outlook.exe present for a particular machine so it doesn't show in the result set. I would like to find a way to show it even when the outlook.exe file does not exist.

Here is my current query that I was trying to get to work but it still fails to show the machine that comes up when I drop out the last line.

```
   SELECT Distinguished_Name0, Full_Domain_Name0, User_Name0, Netbios_Name0, OS.Caption0, IP_Addresses0, SystemType0, Model0, SYS.ResourceID,
[Office2013] = CASE 
    WHEN  [FileName] = 'outlook.exe' and left(FileVersion, 2) = '15'     THEN 'TRUE'
    WHEN Not Exists (Select * from v_GS_SoftwareFile where SF.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceID and [FileName] = 'outlook.exe') THEN 'FALSE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
END

FROM v_R_System SYS 

INNER JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS 
ON SYS.ResourceID = OS.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses IP
ON SYS.ResourceID = IP.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CO
ON SYS.ResourceID = CO.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN  v_GS_SoftwareFile SF
ON SYS.ResourceID = SF.ResourceID

WHERE sys.Distinguished_Name0 LIKE '%DC=local'
AND sys.Distinguished_Name0 NOT LIKE '%Server%'
AND IP_Addresses0 LIKE '10.0.0.%' 
AND Model0 LIKE '%%'
AND OS.Caption0 <> 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise'
AND (SF.[FileName] = 'outlook.exe' 
OR NOT EXISTS (Select * from v_GS_SoftwareFile where SF.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID and [FileName] = 'outlook.exe'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `not exists` query doesn't work is because the alias `SF` in your subquery is referring to to the `v_GS_SoftwareFile` of your outer query, not your subquery.

```
AND (SF.[FileName] = 'outlook.exe' 
OR NOT EXISTS (Select * from v_GS_SoftwareFile where SF.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID and [FileName] = 'outlook.exe'))
                                                     ^^ this is referring to outer v_GS_SoftwareFile
```

`SF.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID` will always be true (due to the join condition), so the `not exists` query will always return false if at least 1 row in the table has `outlook.exe` for `FileName`

You'll need to give the table in your subquery another alias

```
AND (SF.[FileName] = 'outlook.exe' 
OR NOT EXISTS (Select * from v_GS_SoftwareFile SF2 where SF2.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID and [FileName] = 'outlook.exe'))
```

I'm probably not understanding your question. But if the goal is to show machines whether outlook.exe exists or not, then why not simply remove `outlook.exe` from your where clause?

Comment: Thank you for spelling this out, totally makes sense now. I will try and see how this changes the result set. Goal is to show a Boolean column of when outlook.exe version is equal to defined version, but also show when it does not exist. Currently failing on showing when not existing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an outer join:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM v_R_System SYS INNER JOIN
     v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS 
     ON SYS.ResourceID = OS.ResourceID INNER JOIN
     v_RA_System_IPAddresses IP
     ON SYS.ResourceID = IP.ResourceID INNER JOIN
     v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CO
     ON SYS.ResourceID = CO.ResourceID LEFT JOIN
     v_GS_SoftwareFile SF
     ON SYS.ResourceID = SF.ResourceID AND
        SF.[FileName] = 'outlook.exe' 
WHERE sys.Distinguished_Name0 LIKE '%DC=local' AND
      sys.Distinguished_Name0 NOT LIKE '%Server%' AND
      IP_Addresses0 LIKE '10.0.0.%' AND
      Model0 LIKE '%%' AND
      OS.Caption0 <> 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise'
```

Comment: Where are you doing an outer join?

Comment: @ssaviers . . . That is very strange.  Not only was the outer join missing but the following line was not indented correctly.  I must've inadvertently deleted some stuff before putting in the answer.